# Saving a foreign key using entity with only id valorized

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

If I have two hibernate entities like:

```
@Entity
class Company {
     @Id
     Integer id;
     String name;
}

@Entity
class Person {
     Integer id;
     String name;
     @ManyToOne
     Company company;
}
```

I have an already stored company like `Company(id:1, name:"Acme")`

Can I create a person referencing the company with just its id instead of load the entire record, like:

```
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
Company acme = new Company();
acme.setId(1);
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Manuel");
person.setCompany(acme);

session.save(person);
```

Does it save just the reference, or also update the company with `name=null`?

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the actual `Company` from the db and add it to a `User`?

Comment: You are creating a new company object with the same PK as an existing company object. Hibernate will try to insert it and the database will throw an error in its face if the `id` column is defined as a PK column with the relevant constraint in the db. You need to read the company by PK from the DB and add it.

Comment: @LordAnomander I'm working with legacy code, and I have this situation with 'state' object, like a request that is (sketch, sent, approved, bla, bla) and each state is an entity, so each time you have to change the state to something you have a line like `ObjectState state = stateDao.findById(Constants.OBJECT_STATE_APPROVED)`, I would like to remove this line, because they are a lot, and just add entropy to the codebase! I tought to create a fake enum with all the states as object valorized with just the PK.

Comment: @JohannesJander It depends of mapping (cascade exactly). For this mapping you are not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

> Does it save just the reference, or also update the company with
>   name=null?

With default `cascade`, like that, Hibernate will do nothing. So answer is: It  saves just a foreign key.

The most valid (for JPA too) approach is using `session.load(Company.class, 1)`. It returns a proxy without do any request to the database. But, you need to have a session for it, of course.

Comment: I have this situation with 'state' object, like a request that is (sketch, sent, approved, bla, bla) and each state is an entity, so each time you have to change the state to something you have a line like `ObjectState state = stateDao.findById(Constants.OBJECT_STATE_APPROVED)`. I would like to create manually an enum with all these state entities valorized with just their id (right now I have the same but with their id), but I was not sure if it can work. thx